# Custom vue events not working

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

I am trying to catch vue.js custom event within one component, but it's not catching. What's the problem?

```
myEventFunc: function() {
  this.myEvent = true;
},
clickedFunc: function() {
  this.clicked = true;
  this.$emit('myevent');
}
```

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ucean0rh/1/

Comment: The event system is to catch an event from a child component inside a parent component which wraps that child. Your example does not even have 2 components and is doing something entirely different. It is meant for `child-parent` communication.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a Vue way of dealing with it, but it works in my JSFiddle. Simply call `myEventFunc()` from within `clickedFunc`:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myEvent: false,
    clicked: false,
  },
  methods: {
    myEventFunc: function() {
      this.myEvent = true;
    },
    clickedFunc: function() {
      this.clicked = true;
      this.myEventFunc();
      this.$emit('myevent');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Vue can deal with it according to documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events